# Odd UITableView height behavior with NSZombieEnabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, memory-management

I am setting my height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    CGFloat rowHeight = 0;

    if(indexPath.row == [self.items count]){ //more
        rowHeight = 50.0; //same as moreCell 
    }
    else{
        ChartlyCell *cell = (ChartlyCell*)[self tableView:tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        rowHeight = cell.totalHeight;
    }

    return rowHeight;   
}
```

Here is how `cell.totalHeight` is calculated:

```
-(float)totalHeight {
    float h = messageLabel.totalheight + 35;
    if(h < 68) h = 68;
    return h;
}
```

My simulator crashes with no debug errors when `NSZombieEnabled = NO`. Simulator runs fine when `NSZombieEnabled = YES`. Not sure how to resolve?

**UPDATE:**
This is how I am building my initializing my cell:

```
cell = [[[ChartlyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier andDelegate:self andChartlyDelegate:self andChartlyObj:myChartlyObject]autorelease];
```

If I remove the autorelease, everything runs fine. I am still confused why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Cocoa Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Assuming that `cell` is an instance variable, consider:

```
cell = [[[ChartlyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                               andDelegate:self
                        andChartlyDelegate:self
                             andChartlyObj:myChartlyObject]autorelease];
```

This will cause `cell` to be reaped when the pool is drained, thus leaving `cell` pointed to a now-deallocated instance of `ChartlyCell`.   If you want an object to stick around, it must be retained.  A retain is implied by `alloc` and effectively undone by `autorelease`.  Removing the `autorelease` keeps the object around.

The simulator should have barfed an error back with zombies enabled.  Odd that it didn't.  File a bug via http://bugreport.apple.com/ and attach a built copy of the crashing version of your application with a link to this SO question.